# Razorpay cordova plugin not working for iOS stuck on splash screen

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, razorpay

I'm trying to implement Razorpay checkout in my ionic application using Razorpay-cordova. After installing this plugin, ios application gets stuck on its splash screen and then gets close. Although this plugin works perfectly on Android platforms.

I have done following basic steps:

Added razorpay plugin - cordova plugin add com.razorpay.cordova --save

After this I emulate this basic app just in ios simulator - ionic cordova emulate ios

I have embedded swift libraries in Xcode the razorpay.framework.

Then imported the <razorpay-swift.h> in main.m.

Result: The app gets stuck on the splash screen for few secs and then gets close. (Only on IOS. Also tested on IOS device, results in same!).

I don't know what I'm missing here?

Comment: try to debug your IOS application on device and see console for Errors.

Comment: does not shows any Errors in the console. @Najam Us Saqib